# Get The Public IP Address Of The User Who Is Visiting My Website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I tried this below code. But it returned me `::1`

```
string IPAddress = string.Empty;
string SearchName = string.Empty;

            String strHostName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress.ToString();

            IPAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(strHostName).GetValue(0).ToString();
```

I expect output should be Something like : `(358.89.48.188)`

So I'm looking forward for anyone who could help me out.

(By getting this I will get the location and pass it to Session,So my Controller and action reacts based on the client location)

Comment: ::1 stands for localhost. So if you try to test it locally. You will always get this.

Comment: @SehaxX so if i deploy and try in site can i expect it to work fine

Comment: @gokul: What happens when you access this from a different (non-localhost) system?

Comment: what is value of strHostName? It should contain IP in string format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is IP address '::1'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611418/what-is-ip-address-1)

Comment: @David when i access from non local host the IP Address is returning the Public Ip of My hosted server,But i need the user's accessing my site

Comment: @gokul Try this HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]  instead of Request.UserHostAddress which returns server IP which IIS runs on.

Comment: @SehaxX Will let u know after trying this

Comment: @SaurabhHarwande   i just copied this code from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798286/ip-address-of-the-user-who-is-browsing-my-website     and below is my code where I am able to get the Public Ip address of my system ,not the client System     string externalIP;
            externalIP = (new WebClient()).DownloadString("http://checkip.dyndns.org/");
            externalIP = (new Regex(@"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}"))
                         .Matches(externalIP)[0].ToString();

Comment: @SehaxX it didnt worked

Comment: The problem is with the last line. You already have got the address inside String strHostName. You just need to IPAddress.Parse(strHostName) instead of Dns resolving.

Comment: @SaurabhHarwande Returning my server address(Mumbai IP) but I am accessing from TamilNadu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Heading ##Hey All Thanks For Your Contribution ,I Got Answer By Using The Following Code,Hope It Might Help Some One In Future ## Heading ##

```
    public string GetVisitorIPAddress(bool GetLan = false)
    {
        string visitorIPAddress = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
                   if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(visitorIPAddress))
            visitorIPAddress = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
                  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(visitorIPAddress))
            visitorIPAddress = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(visitorIPAddress) || visitorIPAddress.Trim() == "::1")
        {
            GetLan = true;
            visitorIPAddress = string.Empty;
        }
        if (GetLan)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(visitorIPAddress))
            {
                //This is for Local(LAN) Connected ID Address
                string stringHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
                //Get Ip Host Entry
                IPHostEntry ipHostEntries = Dns.GetHostEntry(stringHostName);
                //Get Ip Address From The Ip Host Entry Address List
                IPAddress[] arrIpAddress = ipHostEntries.AddressList;
                try
                {
                    visitorIPAddress = arrIpAddress[arrIpAddress.Length - 2].ToString();
                }
                catch
                {
                    try
                    {
                        visitorIPAddress = arrIpAddress[0].ToString();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            arrIpAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses(stringHostName);
                            visitorIPAddress = arrIpAddress[0].ToString();
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            visitorIPAddress = "127.0.0.1";
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        }

        var zaz = "";
        zaz = visitorIPAddress.ToString();
        getcityname(zaz);
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

try this...

```
 public string GetIpAddress()
    {
         var ipAddress=Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
         if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
         {
             return Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
         }
         return ipAddress;
    }
```

Comment: execute it on server( non- local) system.

Comment: External IP166.91.48.188
Loaded PlaceOK;;89.129.8.172;IN;India;Maharashtra;Mumbai;400099;19.0144;72.8479;+05:30    ,this is what i got in my logger but i need the users(customer accessing my site's Public Ip)  this ip is my public Ip address

Comment: @gokul - one question for more clarification- for example if user is accessing your website (abc.com) using IP address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  (pointing locally abc.com to xxx in host file), where user's public IP is yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy, so do you want xxx or yyy?

Comment: My site is hosted in Mumbai Based Ip and if my Customer access it from Tamilnadu , I need the Ip Address Of his system so while converting its Ip address i will get a place from Tamilnadu

Comment: @gokul - Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"], should give you yyy part. So do you think 89.129.8.172 in your log is not user's address?

Comment: actually for privacy reason , i changed my return ip as 89.129.8.172 ,btw i checked the ip address from this site http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx